# apex check if specific scheduled job is running now

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

assuming I have Scheduleable class called 'MyscheduledClass' , how do i check if this class is running now as scheduled job ?
I dont means to check if it's was scheduled , just if it is running now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query [AsynsApexJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) object. A sample query would be;

```
AsyncApexJob aaj = [SELECT Id, Status, ApexClassID FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ApexClassID = 'your schedulable class id'];

if(aaj.Status == 'Processing'){
     //running
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the class name:

```
AsyncApexJob aJob= [ 
                    SELECT Id, Status, ApexClassID 
                    FROM AsyncApexJob 
                    WHERE ApexClass.Name = 'your schedulable class name'
];

if(aJob.Status == 'Processing'){
}
```